# Need SQL help returning a dynamic dataset

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables I would like to query for a single dataset.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT u.Name, r.Description from Users u 
JOIN UserRoleMembership m ON m.UserID = u.UserID
JOIN UserRoles r ON r.RoleID = m.RoleID
GROUP BY u.UserID
```

The problem is that the above query only returns the first Role.  How can I get the User.Name and a list of Roles on a single row?

Users (Distinct Users)

```
INSERT into Users (UserID, Name) Values
(0, Me),
(1, Me2);
```

UserRoles (Distinct Role, and Role description)

```
INSERT into Users (RoleID, Description) Values
(0, Everyone),
(1, Users),
(2, Admin);
```

UserRoleMembership (one user may have more than one role)

```
INSERT into UserRoleMembership (MembershipID, UserID, RoleID) Values
(0, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 1),
(2, 1, 0),
(3, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the fields you want to see. In this case, `group by u.name, r.description` instead of grouping by userid.

It is a would-be-handy feature from MySQL, which is actually very confusing I think. Most DBs wouldn't even allow this query. You should not be able to have fields in your select that are not in the group by, unless you aggregate them somehow (use `min` or `max` or so).

[edit]

If you want the descriptions in a single row per user, group by userid (of rather u.name), and use GROUP_CONCAT(r.Description) to aggregate the roles.

Comment: well what I was hoping for was a single row, containing the user's name, and a list of roles.

Comment: In that case, use the GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function.